# Can Drools have Drl file without having any associated POJO classes?

Tags: java, drools, rules

Can we create a drools drl file with facts/fields/variables in when and then blocks, without associating them to any class object?

```
>     ***NORMAL DRL***--  
>      when
>         m : Message( status == Message.HELLO, myMessage : message )
>     then
>         System.out.println( myMessage );
>         m.setMessage( "Goodbye cruel world" );
>         m.setStatus( Message.GOODBYE );
>         update( m ); 
>         end
>     ***DRL EXPECTED***--  
>       when
>        status == "HELLO";
>       then
>         myMessage == "Goodbye cruel world";
>       end
```

Is something like this possible, where we don't have to create pojo or setter-getter classes for creating an object? Is association of a variable/fact/field to object neccesary?

Here, m is an object of a class Message,
Variables are status and myMessage.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? E.g. by adding code, commands or screen shots which describe your problem. Please have also a look to the Help Center, especially for [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: I have edited my question. So, if you can now please look at it.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

Rules operate on facts, which are Java objects in the case of Drools.  I'm not clear what the DRL you would like to write is supposed to represent, but that is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote:
> I know its very old question but currently i was struggling with the same issue and was unable to find any working solution. Finally i have found a solution and have created a sample for the same.

It uses a Generic Java Pojo class with hashmap as attributes.
This sample can be used if you want to select DRL files dynamically and fire the rules on the basis of some criteria.
Not adding the code here as the full code is available here

https://github.com/kirtimandwade20/SpringBootSamples/tree/main/Drools-Sample-DRLFile